# Why does .isdigit not properly work and instead continue?

Tags: python

It's meant to check for a phonenumber and its validity.

The first part checks the starting digits.
The second part checks all the characters.
The next part checks the length,
and the final part is if the starting digits are incorrect

```
while True:
  print("")
  print("Enter your phone number below.")
  phonenumber = input("")
  # if phonenumber has the right starting digits
  if phonenumber[0] == "+" and phonenumber[1] == "6" and phonenumber[
      2] == "4" or phonenumber[0] == "0" and phonenumber[1] == "2":
    for i in range(1, len(phonenumber)):
      # checks all characters
      if not phonenumber[i].isdigit():
        print("")
        print("Please use the correct phone number.")
        continue

    # checks the phone number length
      if phonenumber[i].isdigit():
        if len(phonenumber) <= 15 and len(phonenumber) >= 10:
          phonenumber = phonenumber.replace(" ", "")
          details.append(phonenumber)
          print("")
          print("Information successfully inputed.")
          print("")
          print("---------------")
          print("")
          break
          
    else:
      print("")
      print("Please use the correct phone number.")
      continue

  # else if it doesn't start right
  else:
    print("Try again, matey.")
    continue
```

The issue is that if I put 021 at the start, and use the right amount of digits, but with the use of letters. It notices, however it still allows the information to continue.

I tried moving it around but it didn't do much.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at indentation levels of what you posted the `else` is connected with the `for`, not the `if` statement. In python there is a `for...else` (example read [for...else](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause)), which is very rarely used actually, but it's valid nonetheless. The `else` kicks in if the `for` went through "naturally" (other words wasn't interrupted by break statement).
Your code (else not indented properly):

```py
    for i in range(1, len(phonenumber)):
      # checks all characters
      if not phonenumber[i].isdigit():
        print("")
        print("Please use the correct phone number.")
        continue

    # checks the phone number length
      if phonenumber[i].isdigit():
        if len(phonenumber) <= 15 and len(phonenumber) >= 10:
          phonenumber = phonenumber.replace(" ", "")
          details.append(phonenumber)
          print("")
          print("Information successfully inputed.")
          print("")
          print("---------------")
          print("")
          break
          
    else:
      print("")
      print("Please use the correct phone number.")
      continue
```

Code which does what you want presumably (`else` indented to be connected with digit check `if`):

```
    for i in range(1, len(phonenumber)):
      # checks all characters
      if not phonenumber[i].isdigit():
        print("")
        print("Please use the correct phone number.")
        continue

    # checks the phone number length
      if phonenumber[i].isdigit():
        if len(phonenumber) <= 15 and len(phonenumber) >= 10:
          phonenumber = phonenumber.replace(" ", "")
          details.append(phonenumber)
          print("")
          print("Information successfully inputed.")
          print("")
          print("---------------")
          print("")
          break
          
      else:
        print("")
        print("Please use the correct phone number.")
        continue
```